# How do I set-location ad: to a different active directory domain with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I have the Active Directory module installed on my Windows 7 workstation using PowerShell 3 and when I use "Set-Location AD:", it is using my current domain.

Is it possible to set my base location to a different domain?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-Location AD:
Get-ChildItem
```

(shows current DC info)

I would like to switch to a different AD server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this. Assuming your domain name is fabrikam.local

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
New-PSDrive -Name ADFAB -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Server "servername.fabrikam.local" -Scope Global -root "//RootDSE/"
Set-Location ADFAB:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to ssaviers's answer...

If you are working with a mounted ntdsutil AD snapshot, just use "localhost:10389" for the server, using whatever port you used when you mounted the snapshot with dsamain.

+1 for the answer though, New-PSDrive was what I needed to be able to restore corrupted permissions on our domain controller objects using Get-ACL and Set-ACL. I thought AdminSDHolder would fix the issue on its own, seeing as Domain Controllers group is a protected group, but even after trying to kick off that process manually we weren't seeing any results.